# MySQL - Update Column Value with Function and Trigger Before Insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

i'm trying to update 2 column with trigger before insert, but i have unexpected result. i insert some data and the 2 last column will automatically inserted with values, here my first attempt
[image]

see? the last 2 column is null even i set some trigger and function to fill that columns automatically. Here my second attempt WITH EXACTLY SAME DATA

[image]

the last 2 column is filled with data, but i don't understand why the first attempt is fail?

here my trigger i use in the column total_harga

```
CREATE TRIGGER `set_total_harga` BEFORE INSERT ON `tbl_transaksi_detail`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
set NEW.total_harga = hitungTotalHargaPerItem(NEW.qty, NEW.harga_satuan);
END
```

trigger for column harga_satuan

```
CREATE TRIGGER `set_harga_satuan` BEFORE INSERT ON `tbl_transaksi_detail`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
set NEW.harga_satuan = set_Harga_Unit(NEW.unit, NEW.id_barang, NEW.no_transaksi);
END
```

function set_Harga_Unit

```
  BEGIN
  DECLARE
    q,
    id_toko INT;
  SET
    id_toko =(
    SELECT DISTINCT
      `tbl_transaksi`.`id_toko`
    FROM
      `tbl_transaksi`,
      `tbl_transaksi_detail`
    WHERE
      `tbl_transaksi`.`no_transaksi` = no_trans
  ); IF unit = "PCS" THEN
SET
  q =(
  SELECT
    `tbl_harga_jual`.`harga_pcs`
  FROM
    `tbl_harga_jual`
  WHERE
    `tbl_harga_jual`.`id_barang` = id_brg AND `tbl_harga_jual`.`id_toko` = id_toko
); RETURN q; ELSEIF unit = "PAK" THEN
SET
  q =(
  SELECT
    `tbl_harga_jual`.`harga_pak`
  FROM
    `tbl_harga_jual`
  WHERE
    `tbl_harga_jual`.`id_barang` = id_brg AND `tbl_harga_jual`.`id_toko` = id_toko
); RETURN q; ELSEIF unit = "KARTON" THEN
SET
  q =(
  SELECT
    `tbl_harga_jual`.`harga_karton`
  FROM
    `tbl_harga_jual`
  WHERE
    `tbl_harga_jual`.`id_barang` = id_brg AND `tbl_harga_jual`.`id_toko` = id_toko
); RETURN q;
END IF; RETURN q;
END
```

function hitungTotalHargaPerItem

```
BEGIN
DECLARE hasil int;
    set hasil = qty * harga_satuan;
    RETURN hasil;
END
```

Comment: in this function : hitungTotalHargaPerItem  set hasil = qty * harga_satuan; if harga_satuan is null i think the result will be null

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it seem i have mistaken select query in function `set_Harga_Unit`, based on clues from @Shadow

```
SET
    id_toko =(
    SELECT DISTINCT
      `tbl_transaksi`.`id_toko`
    FROM
      `tbl_transaksi`,
      `tbl_transaksi_detail`<<== I DON'T NEED THIS
    WHERE
      `tbl_transaksi`.`no_transaksi` = no_trans
  ); IF unit = "PCS" THEN
```

when first insert in `tbl_transaksi_detail`, the value `no_transaksi` is null because i use trigger `before insert` in empty table (`tbl_transaksi_detail`), so i remove `tbl_transaksi_detail` from query

```
SET
        id_toko =(
        SELECT DISTINCT
          `tbl_transaksi`.`id_toko`
        FROM
          `tbl_transaksi`
        WHERE
          `tbl_transaksi`.`no_transaksi` = no_trans
      ); IF unit = "PCS" THEN
```

now it working, thanks everybody!

Comment: This solution is not sustainable. In the moment you delete a record or probably just have a rollback in `tbl_transaksi` table, then the count will return an incorrect value. Also, it is not safe if you have multiple users trying to insert transaction details at the same time. Even if you do not have multiple users inserting transaction details at the same time, a `max(id_toko)` would be a lot more efficient to get the highest id of transaction. Moreover, your solution is based on the one I provided. So, accepting your own answer is neither correct, nor fair.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause serms to be the select that sets `id_toko` variable's value:

```
  SET
    id_toko =(
    SELECT DISTINCT
      `tbl_transaksi`.`id_toko`
    FROM
      `tbl_transaksi`,
      `tbl_transaksi_detail`
    WHERE
      `tbl_transaksi`.`no_transaksi` = no_trans
  );
```

In the select you inner join `tbl_transaksi_detail` (the table with the trigger in question) on another table. However, in the 1st case `tbl_transaksi_detail` is still **empty** (the trigger is **before** insert), therefore `id_toko` variable is set to null.

This will result `q` being null, which in turn results in the entire calculation set to null.

In the 2nd case there is already a record inserted into `tbl_transaksi_detail` table, therefore the calculation returns a non null value. But it returns the correct values only because the 1st and 2nd records' details are exactly the same.

I do not really understand that select that calculates `id_toko` anyway. If that is a transaction id, then you may use `last_insert_id()` if it is auto increment and the transaction record has just been created or `max(id_toko)` to get the highest value of `id_toko` (this is not multi user safe).